# Declaração de 2 PK Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde.

Tenho a tabela `Icms` que tem como PK a coluna`IcmClaFiscal`, preciso passar a coluna `IcmEmpresa` também como PK,porém o SQL me retorna um alerta. Como já consegui fazer esse procedimento em outros casos através do `Design` e deu certo, fiquei receoso de fazer o mesmo para este caso pois, nos outros não retornou esse alerta. Poderiam me orientar de como proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer uma PK composta ou substituir sua PK antiga pela nova? Além disso qual Banco de dados você está utilizando?

Comment: Quero uma PK composta. Estou usando Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você terá que dropar a sua PK e depois recria-lá, para fazer isso você vai precisar executar os seguintes comandos.

```
ALTER TABLE Icms
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>

ALTER TABLE Icms
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name> PRIMARY KEY (IcmClaFiscal,IcmEmpresa )
```

Onde tem `<constraint_name>` você tem que colocar o nome da sua PK, igual como está no banco de dados